# Match string if underscore encountered before match

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a bit of difficulty with this so I hope you girls and guys can help out, I have several strings like this

```
foo_bar.com                  // no match
foo_bar.com@some.otherstuff  // match
foo_bar.com@some_otherstuff  // match
```

I'm using this, but its not working quite how I want it

`[^_]+(?=@).*`

if an underscore is encountered BEFORE an at I would like to remove the @ and everything afterward, if an underscore is NOT encountered, just leave the string alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
preg_replace('/((?=_).*?)@.*/', '$1', $string);
```

Output:

```
* foo_bar.com                  => foo_bar.com
* foo_bar.com@some.otherstuff  => foo_bar.com
  foobar.com@some.otherstuff   => foobar.com@some.otherstuff
```

Comment: Excellent! Accepted and plus 1 for your troubles Sir

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lookarounds for that:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^([^_@]*_[^@]*)@.+/', '$1', $subject);
```

Comment: Already accepted a working solution, but plus one for doing it without look arounds, thanks Alan, I didn't think you could do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

This needs two steps, first match and then erase.

```
if (preg_match("/_.*@/", $string))
   $string = preg_replace("/@.*$/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a regular expression, you could use basic string functions:

```
$underscore = strpos($string, '_');
$at = strpos($string, '@');

if ($underscore !== false && $underscore < $at) {
   $string = substr($string, 0, $at);
}
```